# code after while loop not Working

Tags: javascript, smarty

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prepare_values()
{ldelim}
        var flag= true;
        var i=0;
    var total_questions = new Array();
    var total_answer = new Array();
        while(flag)
            {ldelim}
            var questions = document.getElementById("question_div_"+i); 
            if (questions == null)
            {ldelim}
                flag=false;
                alert("Value of flag = "+flag);
            {rdelim}

            var answer = document.getElementById("answer_div_"+i);
            total_questions[i]=questions.firstChild.innerHTML; 
            if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'text')
                {ldelim}
                    total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
                {rdelim}

            if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'textarea')
                {ldelim}
                    total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
                {rdelim}

            if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'radio_div')
                {ldelim}
                       var radio_button_parent = document.getElementById(answer.firstChild.id);
                       var oRadio = document.getElementsByName(radio_button_parent.firstChild.name);
                       for(var k = 0; k < oRadio.length; k++)
                       {ldelim}
                          if(oRadio[k].checked)
                          {ldelim}
                             var radio_button_value = document.getElementById(oRadio[k].id);
                             alert("From inside of ever = "+radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML);
                             total_answer[i]=radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML;
                           {rdelim}
                       {rdelim}


                {rdelim}

    i=i+1; 
    {rdelim} 

    alert("hello");
{rdelim}
</script>
```

The above is my JS code which is running in a `SMARTY` template file on click of a button. The Code is Working Fine except that It Does not Run the Third Last Line i.e alert("Hello"); any thing after the `{redelim}` is neglected. What to do ?

here is the code from the firebug:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prepare_values()
{
var flag= true;
var i=0;
var total_questions = new Array();
var total_answer = new Array();
while(flag)
{
var questions = document.getElementById("question_div_"+i);
if (questions == null)
{
flag=false;
alert("Value of flag = "+flag);
}
var answer = document.getElementById("answer_div_"+i);
total_questions[i]=questions.firstChild.innerHTML;
if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'text')
{
total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
}
if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'textarea')
{
total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
}
if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'radio_div')
{
var radio_button_parent = document.getElementById(answer.firstChild.id);
var oRadio = document.getElementsByName(radio_button_parent.firstChild.name);
for(var k = 0; k < oRadio.length; k++)
{
if(oRadio[k].checked)
{
var radio_button_value = document.getElementById(oRadio[k].id);
alert("From inside of ever = "+radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML);
total_answer[i]=radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML;
}
}
}
i=i+1;
}
alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a javascript debugger (F12 in Chrome, F12 in Firefox with Firebug installed, F12 in Internet Explorer, etc.)? Any javascript errors/exceptions/etc.?

Comment: Yes I have tried. No Exceptions.

Comment: The problem is probably not smarty, could you paste the code that is actually inside the html, after being rendered?

Comment: Try amending your flag = false `if` statement to: `if (questions == null || typeof questions == 'undefined')`

Comment: Could you please post the rendered javascript code as it appears in debugger?

Comment: @WillemLabu I tried to alert flag when its value changes from true to false and did alert when the value changes but right then the program terminates.

Comment: I ran the program with while(false) and it alerted Hello as if it was not while loop but was if/else condition.

Comment: Looks like an infinite looping at `while(flag)`. Set a breakpoint at `if (questions == null)` an see if it `questons` ever got the `undefined` value (I'm almost sure it never got it).

Comment: No it never goes into Indefinite Loop I checked By alerting value of Flag. `Flag` turns `False` when `questions == null`.

Comment: Sometimes, if you forget any condition, your loop may slip into an infinite loop. So its good to check for looping infinites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont Know what is the issue in the code and why its not working as it is supposed to but this is how I got my code straight.

This is the new working code :

```
function prepare_values()
{
    var flag= true;
    var i=0;
    var total_questions = new Array();
    var total_answer = new Array();
    while(flag)
    {
        var questions = document.getElementById("question_div_"+i);
        if (questions == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        var answer = document.getElementById("answer_div_"+i);
        total_questions[i]=questions.firstChild.innerHTML;
        if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'text')
            {
                total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
        if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'textarea')
            {
                total_answer[i]=answer.firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
        if(answer.firstChild.attributes['type'].value == 'radio_div')
        {
            var radio_button_parent = document.getElementById(answer.firstChild.id);
            var oRadio = document.getElementsByName(radio_button_parent.firstChild.name);
            for(var k = 0; k < oRadio.length; k++)
                {
                    if(oRadio[k].checked)
                    {
                        var radio_button_value = document.getElementById(oRadio[k].id);
                        alert("From inside of ever = "+radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML);
                        total_answer[i]=radio_button_value.nextSibling.innerHTML;
                    }
                }
        }
    i=i+1;
    }

    alert("hello");
}
```

All I did is I replaced

```
if (questions == null)
{
    flag=false;
    alert("Value of flag = "+flag);
}
```

with

```
if (questions == null)
{
    break;
}
```

Though My problem is Solved I still want to know why my previous code was not working because it was still suppose to work as it was correct. If anyone can point out the problem please do so I will appreciate it.

Comment: Seems a little self-indulgent now, but yeah.. I was going to mention you'll have to `break` at some point. Good on you for figuring it out on your own. :{D

Comment: @WillemLabu I don't know very good English but I thing your comment is somewhat derogatory. Is my Question wrong ?

Comment: Not derogatory at all. You did well figuring it out! :{D

Comment: Sorry Told You my English is Bad. :p LOL